# What is the order of loading for.config files in an ASP.NET web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

When starting an ASP.NET web application the configurations of Web.config are loaded.
As I want to load a elmah.config and a log4net.config, I want to know more about the flow of loading for .config files.

All them will be handled by Global.asax, exist some good patter to load config files?

Comment: This is all done automatically. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: And sections and something that is overrated? What's is most important or what is loaded after? I don't have a actual problem right now, but I'm worried with some side effects splitting my .configs

Comment: You don't need to worry about load order. I just don't get the concern.

Comment: @Oded he asked about the process of loading these since he is already aware they are loaded automatically. He doesn't have (or need to have) a concern/problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some information in [Appendix A: The configuration collection cascade](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx#appendixa) which is part of a [longer article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx) on Configuration in .NET. This doesn't address the impact of the ordering of sections within a single web.config file though. I would assume that the ordering of the external config sections should not matter otherwise you would have random problems if you go to add sections at a later point and just add them at the end (one common place to put them).

Answer (score 0):

First loaded will be web.config, second elmah or log4net depending on order of usage of these components in Global.asax.